# Notepad ++ Replace All not functioning with zero-length matches

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I've been trying to make something work for a (admittedly super embarrassing) project, and have been using the Find and Replace option in Notepad++ to surround some instances of chatlog text with HTML tags for the purpose of writing something on Archive of Our Own. Replacing everything manually would be *incredibly* tedious and it appears all of the existing autoreplacers are either deprecated or don't exist on the internet anymore, so I'm working on my own.

This is the RegEx expression that I've been using in the "find" box:

```
((?<startpesterlog>\G-{2})|(?<endpesterlog>-{2}))|((?<extra>\[TG])|(?<extra2>\[EB]))|((?<DavePrefix>^TG: )(?<davetext>.*))|((?<JohnPrefix>^EB: )(?<johntext>.*))|(?<lastline>\G\Z)
```

and this is the RegEx expression I've been using in the "replace" box:

```
(?{lastline}$+{lastline}</p>:(?{startpesterlog}<p align="center"><span class="black">--:(?{endpesterlog}--</span></p><p class="block">:(?{extra}<span class="dave">[TG]</span>:(?{extra2}<span class="john">[EB]</span>:(?{DavePrefix}<span class="dave">TG\: $+{davetext}<\/span> <br\/>:(?{JohnPrefix}<span class="john">EB\: $+{johntext}<\/span> <br\/>:???)))))))
```

Assuming you use the "replace" button, everything works as intended- the last line of the log is replaced with a </p>, like normal. However, using the "replace all" button, the final </p> is not notated at all. I have no idea why- but it seems to be a problem with the former RegEx rather than the latter, as using the "find all" buttons return one less than expected.

Example:

> -- turntechGodhead [TG] began pestering ectoBiologist [EB] at 16:13 --
>
> TG: sample text
>
> EB: sample text 2

After formatting:

> <p align="center"><span class="black">-- turntechGodhead <span class="dave">[TG]</span> began pestering ectoBiologist <span class="john">[EB]</span> at 16:13 --</span></p><p class="block">
>
> <span class="dave">TG: sample text / <br/>
>
> <span class="john">EB: sample text 2 / <br/> </p>

Thanks.

Comment: One-by-one replace does not produce a `</p>` for me. Notepad++ v7.9.1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's odd. it should highlight just after the last character using find next, if it's not i'll edit the post to include the versions sitting in notepad++'s storage.